# Can't open csv file via command prompt on windows

Tags: python, windows, pandas, command-line

I'm having trouble with the first argument in the pd.read_table function used for Python via Pandas. If I hardcode in the file path of the csv file I want to open and use as a data frame, it works. However, when I receive the file path via a command argument, which saves it into a variable, it won't receive the variable. Any idea why?

I'm using anaconda 2.0.1 on Windows

Comment: Can you provide relevant code?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the same and it worked for me(I am using Ubuntu, but that should not matter). I did the following please crosscheck and see

test.py

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

pd.read_table(sys.argv[1])
```

Then called the function like :

```
test.py /home/user/test.csv
```

Hope this was helpful, in case you are doing something different put a snppet to be more clear